# Verwendung von "so vieles"

Tags: usage

Im heutigen [Facebook-Status](https://www.facebook.com/DerSpiegel/posts/744625538955767) vom *Spiegel* steht:

> Für junge Deutsche ist Angela Merkel die Frau, die immer da war, die **so vieles** bestimmt.

Im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/so_viel) konnte ich nur ein Beispiel zu **so vieles** finden, und es kommt hier ein weiteres Wort dazu:

> so vieles Schöne

Ist die eigenständige Verwendung von **so vieles** überhaupt richtig?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ja, in diesem Fall ist "vieles" ein Indefinitpronomen (hier in der Funktion eines direkten Objekts). Es bedeutet, dass Angie viele verschiedene Sachen bestimmt. Das "so" wirkt verstärkend.

"So viel" wird oft synonym verwendet, kann aber genaugenommen auch als Adverb verstanden werden (z. B., dass sie *oft* bestimmt).

Bei substantivisch gebrauchten Adjektiven fällt dieser Unterschied krasser aus:

> Wir haben so Schönes gesehen. *(z. B. Kunstwerke)*
>   Wir haben so schön gesehen. *(?)*

Als Pronomen kann "vieles" auf jeden Fall alleine stehen. Das Beispiel aus dem Duden klingt für mich besser in der Form "so viel Schönes", es ist aber dennoch richtig. "Schöne" ist in diesem Fall ein substantiviertes, stark gebeugtes Adjektiv.

Answer (score 4):

In diesem Fall dient das Wort „so“ hauptsächlich der Betonung oder Intensivierung.

> so ein schönes Lied! (das ist wirklich ein sehr schönes Lied)
> so ein Pech! (das ist wirklich ein großes Pech)
> so ein Zufall! (das ist wirklich ein großer Zufall)
> *die Frau, die so vieles bestimmt* (die Frau, die wirklich sehr viel bestimmt)

Im Gegensatz zu einigen anderen Verbindungen von „so“ und „viel“, wie z. B. dem Vergleich „er hat doppelt so viel wie du“, könnte man hier das „so“ auch weglassen. Ohne die besondere Betonung heißt es:

> *die Frau, die vieles bestimmt*

Als Indefinitpronomen oder unbestimmtes Zahlwort kann „viel“ zusammen mit einem Substantiv oder einem substantivierten Adjektiv oder auch allein stehen:

> die Frau, die viele Entscheidungen bestimmt
> die Frau, die vieles Wichtige bestimmt
> *die Frau, die vieles bestimmt*

Allerdings wird „viel“ oft ungebeugt verwendet:

> Er trinkt viel.
> Ihr Blick sagte viel.
> Sie weiß viel.
> *die Frau, die viel bestimmt*

Bemerkenswert ist vielleicht noch, dass das Indefinitpronomen und unbestimmte Zahlwort „viel“ grundsätzlich kleingeschrieben wird, auch wenn es formale Merkmale einer Substantivierung aufweist.

> in vielem
> mit vielem
> um vieles
> Ich habe viel[es] erlebt.
> Das haben schon viele erlebt.
> Zum Erfolg trugen auch die vielen bei, die ohne Entgelt mitgearbeitet haben.

Laut *Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* ist jedoch auch Großschreibung zulässig, wenn hervorgehoben werden soll, dass kein unbestimmtes Zahlwort gemeint ist:

> das Lob der vielen
> das Lob der Vielen (= der breiten Masse)

---

In *Duden – Das große Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache* habe ich noch ein paar Beispielsätze gefunden, in denen „so vieles“ so ähnlich wie in der Frage verwendet wird:

> Es ist nicht einsehbar, warum Eltern auf **so vieles** verzichten müssen, damit ihre Kinder später die Renten der Yuppies und Dinks … bezahlen dürfen (Brigitte 26, 1988, 179).
>
> Es war **so vieles** falsch gelaufen, … dass es vielleicht schon zu spät war (H. Weber, Einzug 357)
>
> Weil wir **so vieles** haben, müssen wir uns ständig um dieses sorgen: etwa um den Erhalt von Privilegien, Subventionen und Eigenheimen. Vielleicht fehlt uns einfach Langeweile. In der Überflussgesellschaft wird der Mangel zum Luxus (FAZ 5. 1. 93, 25).